# Detect WinAPI calls

Tags: c#, security, winapi

I'm refactoring an application used by the employees of an insurance carrier, they have had some problems with some kind of malware on their computers that was controlling this application to do bad things, or at least that's what they say.

I'm pretty sure the malware is using the Win API to make calls to the application instance, so my question is, there's any way to detect if a real user is controlling the application or it's being controlled by another process through calls to the Win API? The app is coded in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is coming from my experience with developing Win32 apps using C++.

I can only think of two ways in which the app is being controlled -- one using OLE automation, using automation verbs and secondly inserting keyboard/mouse events into the system event queue. (I'm assuming that this app is not listening for any network originated commands). You can verify the first by checking the source code and using a debugger with some OutputDebugString calls. The second can only be detected by a malware scanner. Any COTS/free AV or MS security essentials should be able to identify a malware, unless of course it's written internally by a malicious employee.

Have you taken a look at the task manager process list and gone through them one-by-one to see if there's anything that looks suspicious? Can you run the app with elevated privileges? Then the OLE automation client, if one is present, won't be able to access the process.

Comment: There are more possibilities: injecting messages into the window message queue (very different from the system input queue), or installing virtual input drivers that send input messages through exactly the same path as a real mouse/keyboard.  In extreme cases, where a keyboard's firmware is infected, there's no difference on the computer side whatsoever, making detection very difficult.

Comment: Ah, that's correct. Forgot about the message queue approach. As for the second approach, wouldn't the messages eventually end up in the thread's input queue, much like what happens with the keybd_event/mouse_event calls?

Comment: Yes, but I believe that `keybd_event`, `mouse_event`, and `SendInput` set a flag on the message that it was software-generated.  Input coming in through the driver stack won't be flagged like that.

Comment: Thank you guys for pointing me up on the right direction. Actually I don't have access to their computers, they have a technician that takes cares of them and I guess he's who made the report I'm working with. I'll try to get further information on this.